# Is it possible to create an protobuf object with type function in Python? If so how?

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers

We have a db table where we keep payload and type of the messages that sent to pubsub for retry purposes. The problem I am having is, I don't have the reference of the object but I have the type of it as a string.

I am wondering if it is possible to use that type string to initialise that object and update its attributes depending what I have in the payload.

Our objects are generated protobufs coming from proto files.

What I want to do is something like this but I couldn't find a way to do it.

```
msg_type = "<class 'example.protobuf.pubsub.example.example_pb2.ExampleMessage'>"
payload = {"key": "value", "key2": "value"}

example_message = create_protobuf_object(msg_type)

# then update its values with payload (Which I can figure out by myself).
```

I don't want to use hacky solutions like `eval` or having if else statements that generate object according to type.

Comment: There are no hacky solutions to this -- this is a hack. Why would you expect there to be some way to do this from this arbitrary string?

Comment: You mention the `type` function. The type function should give you the actual type, not the string, in which case, you can probably use that type directly to create the object

Comment: Yes but, I am getting this from db. so it is string now

Comment: So then probably you just need to find a hack, and stop using the string representation of an object as a serialization technique, it isn't meant to be used that way, so just using "`eval` or having if else statements that generate object according to type" would both be reasonable solutions in this case

Comment: If this can't be done with string as you said (I have spent some time trying to generate from string as well). I wonder if I save type as bytes into db and try to generate with that (assuming I am able to convert that byte back to type when I read it). Do you think this is valid solution to this problem?

Comment: This can definitely be solved with the Well Known Type called [struct](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) and a little bit of parsing. However, I'm not sure you want to go down that road because this has a lot of edge cases... For the bytes thing that you mentioned, this is also possible but you'll have to have guarantee on the serialization/deserialization type otherwise it will throw exceptions.

Comment: @DogukanEvcil you need to *pick some serialization format* and use that.

Comment: Thank you all for valuable inputs. @ClémentJean changing message value to struck is not an option here since there are lots of messages that will use this functionality.

Comment: @DogukanEvcil Depending on the language, you can transform that struct to a message. But be careful this is language specific